# Whenever I am closing the pop up ,the page is getting refresh, i don't want page to get refresh

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, popup

I am using a Boolean variable in my lwc that is, `modalPopUpToggleFlag`. When `modalPopUpToggleFlag` is `true` it opens the pop up, here is my event handler to close pop-up

```
closeModal() {
    this.modalPopUpToggleFlag = false;
}
```

Whenever it is closing the pop up it is refreshing the whole page, I don't want to refresh the page.
This is the html

```
 <template if:true={modalPopUpToggleFlag}>
                    <lightning-card  class="slds-border_top slds-border_bottom slds-border_left slds-border_right slds-card slds-card_boundary" >
                    <c-l-W-C_-L-O-S_-O-T-P onadd={colorChange} ></c-l-W-C_-L-O-S_-O-T-P>
                    </lightning-card>
                </template>
```

Comment: Hey Ruchi, welcome to the Salesforce Stack Exchange! I've never used lwc myself, only the aura / native lightning components within Salesforce. But I know that I ran into a similar issue when my button was comprised of an anchor tag (<a>) with an href. The native functionality loads whatever the link points to, and it also runs the javascript logic. Might be something similar in your case.

It can be resolved by either removing the href in the button element, or calling the event's preventDefault() method.

Comment: @ruchi jain, just a heads up, consider changing how you name your lwc components `c-l-W-C_-L-O-S_-O-T-P` not very intuitive